# Plugin Variable.php Problem

Tags: plugin-development

I want to get the developer name from Plugin.php using the getDeveloper() method so I created a function devName() in Variable.php

```
public function devName() {
    return craft()->crmPortal->getDeveloper();
}
```

but when i want it to print it in my template, using this `{{craft.crmPortal.devName}}` I'm having this Error. Property "Craft\WebApp.crmPortal" is not defined.

Comment: Two things - you're using `devName` and `getName` ... and as I mentioned, it may be a case sensitivity issue - what's the actual class name of your plugin that you've defined?

And you've installed your plugin in setting right?

Comment: Yup ! i installed it in plugin settings. the class name in my CrmPortalPlugin.php is => class CrmPortalPlugin

Comment: Craft\CrmPortalService and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getDeveloper". I'm getting this error right now

Comment: Yes, because you have called the function devName() above...so use `.devName` in your twig code.  All this stuff is very name sensitive.

Comment: do i need to right something in services ?

Comment: You need to implement your function to return that data...which could be via a call to a service, or you could make the developer name a static class var...lots of ways really!

Comment: How should i call it on a service . I'm sorry if ask many questions. i'm just a beginner in craft cms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're attempting to access the `getDeveloper` method on your plugin's main [service class](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/services), but the class doesn't exist.

You have two options:

1. Create the service class, and implement a `getDeveloper` method.
2. Call the `getDeveloper` method on your main plugin class (which I suspect is what you're really trying to do).

### Option One: Service

Your minimal service class will look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

class CrmPortalService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{
    /**
     * Returns the developer name.
     *
     * You could either hard-code the developer name, or you could
     * retrieve it from the main plugin class, as described in
     * option two.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDeveloper()
    {
        return 'John Doe';
    }
}
```

### Option Two: Plugin

Craft uses Services to expose functionality, in exactly the same way that plugins do. If you're trying to figure out how to do something, just look for a Craft Service with a similar name.

In this case, you want to retrieve your main plugin file, so [the `PluginsService`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/PluginsService) is a good place to start. We're in luck, it has [a `getPlugin` method](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/PluginsService#getPlugin-detail), which accepts a plugin handle, and returns the plugin class.

Here's how you might use that, to call the `getDeveloper` method in your main plugin class.

```
craft()->plugins->getPlugin('crmPortal')->getDeveloper();
```

Comment: I want to access the getDeveloper() method in the CrmPortalPlugin.php and print it into the screen

Comment: What I did was I create a function developerName() in Variable.php and  put the craft()->plugins->getPlugin('crmPortal')->getDeveloper();. And i used it in my template to print it on the screen using {{ craft.crmPortal.developerName() }}

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted. If you haven't already done so, I recommend having a read through [the plugin development documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction), to understand how the various elements of a plugin work together.

Comment: Thank you sir . Can you also give me an advice on what to read if i want to make an http request in craft cms?

Comment: I take it you mean an HTTP request from your plugin to an external site (such as an API)? If so, you should take a look at [Guzzle](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/docs.html) (version 3 is a bit out of date, but it's what Craft uses internally, so it's easier to just stick with that).

Comment: Yes Sir. Thanks . This will be a great help to me